# .htaccess - Force urls from 'dir/page.html' → 'dir/page'

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I would like to remove all trailing extension for a spefic file type (for instance remove all `.html` and let everything else as is)

So, for example, if an user goes on the page `<my-site>/how-to/use-git.html`, he would be redirected to `<my-site>/how-to/use-git` (with or without trailing /). Any other request (like `<my-site>/how-to/img1.jpg`) would be left as is (`<my-site>/how-to/img1.jpg`).

While browsing around, I couldn't find something satisfying the following conditions (both):

- Remove the .html
- Force to go to the url without extension

I tried things like this

```
# From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553722/htaccess-mod-rewrite-how-to-modify-url-from-pages-pagename-cfm-to-pagename
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+pages/(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ pages/$1.html [L]
```

But it doesn't force pages to go to the version without extension.

Adding

```
# From http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/web-redirection.shtml
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ $1
```

creates 404 not found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect /path/file.html to /path/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=302]

## To internally redirect /path/file to /path/file.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```